# SQL Server бэкап базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Я работаю с базой данных на SQL Server, ее размер около 100 Gb. Чтобы уменьшить риск потери данных выполняю бэкапы по расписанию при помощи сторонней программы.

Как вы думаете бэкапы - это хороший способ чтобы защитить данные или я что -то упускаю и нужно это добавить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если вы храните действительно ценные данные, потеря которых между полными бэкапами вас огорчит - то вам стоит пересмотреть подход к бэкапам.

Что такое "полный бэкап"? Это полная копия базы в конкретный момент времени. Если вы делаете только полные бэкапы - то в случае чего вы потеряете все данные с момента полного бэкапа. А делать полные бэкапы часто вам не даст размер вашей базы.

К счастью, SQL Server работает с данным не только на уровне "записать в базу". В нем есть еще и фишка под названием "лог транзакций" и "full recovery mode".

Лог транзакций - это .ldf файл, по умолчанию лежащий рядом с .mdf.

Если присмотреться, то при записи любых изменений в базу происходит следующее:

- приходит запрос от клиента `INSERT что-то там`
- SQL Server меняет данные в памяти и по-быстрому записывает *сам факт* вставки в лог транзакций (ldf), просто дописывая его в конц лога.
- SQL Server отчитывается клиенту "все ок, запись вставлена".
- Раз в минуту SQL Server делает checkpoint - записывает на диск сами измененные данные (mdf).
- SQL Server дописывает в лог "изменения по таким-то транзакциям сохранены на диск".

В Full Recovery Mode файл лога хранит в себе все изменения, внесенные с момента создания базы. В том порядке, в котором их вносили.

Файл лога обрезается автоматически в момент бэкапа лога - т.е. когда SQL Server уверен, что данные о внесенных транзакциях вы куда-то сохранили. При этом бэкап лога содержит только изменения, внесенные со времени предыдущего бэкапа лога. Т.е. его размер обычно *значительно меньше* размера полного бэкапа.

(Кстати, тот факт, что вы не бэкапите лог, скорее всего означает что ваша база и ваш полный бэкап сейчас весит в 2 раза больше, чем положено).

Суть всего этого - имея полный бэкап базы недельной давности + бэкап логов, снятый 5 минут назад вы можете восстановить состояние базы на **любой момент** в течении этой недели.

Ваша схема бэкапов должна выглядеть так:

- Полный бэкап базы раз в неделю.
- Бэкап логов раз в 5-15 минут/час, в зависимости от допустимых потерь.

Эта схема легко настраивается через стандартный механизм Maintenance Plan (если у вас не Express). Или вашей сторонней утилитой - она наверняка умеет поддерживать бэкап логов.

---

Кроме того, если у вас SQL Server Standard или выше, то в нем есть встроенный [Managed Backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dn449491(v=sql.120).aspx), который автоматичеcки настраивает эту схему, подбирая интервалы исходя из объемов данных + включет сжатие бэкапов + льет бэкапы в Azure Storage. Т.е. решает проблему поддержания бэкапов с минимальными расходами на их организацию :)

Answer (score 1):

Это зависит от того, от чего Вы защищаетесь. Если вы боитесь потерять данные, то да, бекапов достаточно. Если же хотите защититься от кражи данных, то надо думать о других средствах безопасности. Классический пример: хранение паролей в хеше.

**UPD.** Только бекапы лучше всего хранить на другой машине!

Comment: Насчёт "на другой машине" - да. Иначе смысла особого нет(учитывая текст вопроса автора). +1

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.

Крайне рекомендую в качестве решения для сохранения и проверки бэкапов в SQL Server использовать легендарный набор скрпиптов https://ola.hallengren.com/ (потратьте пару часов на их изучение, столько же на настройку и о проблеме бэкапов в SQL Server можно беспокоиться значительно меньше).

Теперь о самой методологии бэкапа. Выделите 3 часа и прочитайте обязательно следующие 4 статьи (осторожно английский): [Help, my database is corrupt. Now what?](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Corruption/65804/), [What to Do When DBCC CHECKDB Reports Corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/05/dbcc-checkdb-reports-corruption/), [Questions You Should Ask About the Databases You Manage](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/06/questions-ask-databases-manage/) и самая важная в контексе вашего вопроса [The 9 Letters That Get DBAs Fired](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/12/letters-that-get-dbas-fired/).

От себя добавлю: обязательно в письменном виде согласуйте с вашим начальником (или начальником начальника) самые главные метрики:

- **RPO** (Recovery Point Objective) - это минимальное время (в минутах или часах) в течении которого допустима потеря данных в вашей базе данных (т.е. если случилась беда в 12:59 дня, а вы делаете бэкапы каждые пол часа, то вы потеряете все данные, которые были изменены с 12:30)
- **RTO** (Recovery Time Objective) - сколько времени необходимо на восстановление бэкапа

Ну и, конечно же, помимо создания самих бэкапов (с утвержденной политикой их созадния) их (бэкапы) на регулярной основе необходимо проверять на целостность, про это, к сожалению, на регулярной основе, многие забывают.

P.S. Не совсем по теме бэкапов, но по моему мнению крайне полезные скрпипты для мониторинга проблем с SQL Server абсолютно бесплатно можно найти здесь: [Github Brent](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit), а дополнительные материалы по углублению в мир SQL Server здесь: [Github sqlserver-kit](https://github.com/ktaranov/sqlserver-kit)

Answer (score 0):

Бэкап не спасёт вас от потери уже совершенных транзакций.
Пусть у вас бэкап раз в сутки, в течении суток у вас накупили товара на одил биллион рублей.
В ваш сервер ударила молния:)
Чем в этом случае вам бэкап поможет? Лучше чем ничего, конечно.
Нужно думать о рисках и рассматривать варианты их минимизации..
Помимо бэкапов есть точки сохранения БД(по стуи моменты окончания транзакций), которые весят намного меньше, чем полный бекап.
итого бэкап + некоторое количество точек сохранения смогут вам вернуть **согласованное** состояние БД перед ударом молнии.